# Count the occurrences of each element using Stream API and create HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an array that contains duplicate elements likes

```
[ "10.0.0.1 - frank [10/Dec/2000:12:34:56 -0500] \"GET /a.gif HTTP/1.0\" 200 234", 
"10.0.0.1 - frank [10/Dec/2000:12:34:57 -0500] \"GET /b.gif HTTP/1.0\" 200 234", 
"10.0.0.2 - nancy [10/Dec/2000:12:34:58 -0500] \"GET /c.gif HTTP/1.0\" 200 234",
"10.0.0.2 - nancy [10/Dec/2000:12:34:58 -0500] \"GET /c.gif HTTP/1.0\" 200 234",
"10.0.0.3 - nancy [10/Dec/2000:12:34:58 -0500] \"GET /c.gif HTTP/1.0\" 200 234" ]
```

I want to convert this arrays to HashMap so my HashMap should look like this

```
"10.0.0.1" : 2 
"10.0.0.2" : 2 
"10.0.0.3" : 1
```

To make HashMap I wrote this code using Stream API.

```
final Map<String, Integer> ipMap = Arrays.stream(lines)
     .map(ip -> ip.substring(0, ip.indexOf(" ")))
     .collect(Collectors
           .toMap(x -> x, x -> 1));
```

In above code, I know that I have used `x -> 1` inside `.toMap`. Because I don't know what to write.

This is an error I am getting.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate
>   key 1

**I am looking for an answer using Stream API.**

Comment: Use `groupingBy(x -> x, counting())`

Comment: It is not working. It suggests that create counting() method.

Comment: counting() is a static import, you have to add it in your import list, or use the Class reference.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I am not able to find static import for counting(). What is a class of the counting() method?

Comment: It's a collector.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks man. It's working. Appreciate your time.